# opencv fatal signal 11 in find_nearest

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm developing an Android app with opencv

I use the below code for find nearest after CvKNearest train

```
for(int i=0; i< contours.size();i++){
 if ((Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) > 50 )){
  Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
   if (rect.height > 28){
    Mat ROI = imageA.submat(rect.y, rect.y + rect.height, rect.x, rect.x + rect.width);
    Mat tmp1 = new Mat();
    Mat tmp2 = new Mat();
    Mat tmp3 = new Mat(CvType.CV_32FC1);

    Imgproc.resize(ROI, tmp1, new Size(10, 10));
    tmp1.convertTo(tmp2, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    //float p = knn.find_nearest(tmp2.reshape(1, 1), 100, tmp3, temp1, temp1);

    Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x,rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height),new Scalar(0,0,255));

   }
 }
}
```

When I uncomment knn.find_nearest line I receive 
`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)`

Where am I wrong?

When do I have to empty memory??

Answer (score 0):

In the function "find-knearest" you have to check the k parameter, because this has a limit.

Here's a link where you can find the information [link](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/index.html?org/opencv/ml/CvKNearest.html)

I'm in a similar project at the moment, and I set 32 instead of 100.